# Default behavior of a Unix-based shell with respect to child processes on exit?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, signals

I am implementing a basic Unix-based shell. The shell maintains a list of child processes running in background and stopped processes.

If a shell is exited:

- Does the shell kill all the child processes running/stopped in the background?

Or

- Does the shell simply ignore the child processes existing in the background or in stopped state, only to be later adopted by init?

Note that I need to know the exact behavior of the Unix shells. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484397/unix-waiting-on-process-children-upon-exit) but still it doesn't talk about the exact implementation of Unix shells.

Answer (score 1):

Read more about the `SIGHUP` signal. This signal is typically sent to all processes in a process group whenever their controlling terminal exits. In the case of a shell, this usually happens when the terminal window is closed. The default behaviour of the signal is to terminate the process. That is why programs such as `nohup` exist.

In order to write a real shell, you really have to understand the whole TTY subsystem and how signals are related. A recommended article is ["The TTY Demystified"](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Comment: I think you'll find the kernel sends the SIGHUP process to all processes in the process group that has the terminal as its controlling terminal, or thereabouts.  It's a tricky area, with a lot of terminology to master.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `SIGHUP` (signal number is `1`, (to verify `kill -l`)) is signal, which is used to close all the processes (we can say children) , which are running under the terminal, by sending this signal by that terminal to all processes.

```
The SIGHUP signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed. It was 
originally designed to notify the process of a serial line drop (a hangup). In modern   
systems, this signal usually means that the controlling pseudo or virtual terminal has 
been closed.Many daemons will reload their configuration files and reopen their 
logfiles instead of exiting when receiving this signal.nohup is a command to make a 
command ignore the signal.
```